# How to prevent .htaccess redirect rules from cascading to sites held in sub-directories of the 'public_html' root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Basically, I have some sub-directories in the root of the 'public_html' directory (of an Apache server) where I keep my main website ( http://www.jamesandersonjr.com ). The main website files are directly in the 'public_html' root directory, whereas other sites (with their own separate domains), are in sub-folders/sub-directories *under* the root.

The problem I'm having is a few rules in my .htaccess file (in the root of 'public_html') are cascading down, to affect other sites, in the aforementioned sub-directories (and hence, their own separate websites). Here are the rules:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^\/facebook\/?$" "/facebook.php"
RedirectMatch 301 "^\/twitter\/?$" "/twitter.php"
RedirectMatch 301 "^\/youtube\/?$" "/youtube.php"
RedirectMatch 301 "^\/bug_?report\/?$" "/bug_report.php"

RedirectMatch 301 "^\/bugreport\.(php|html?)(\?)?$" "/bug_report.php"
```

These rules are in the .htaccess file at my main website: http://www.jamesandersonjr.com
But at first unbeknownst to me, they also affect another website that is in a sub-directory, of the root directory.

How to prevent this 'cascading' from happening in the first place, or how to rewrite the rules to include only the paths (in the code above) in relation to the main website: http://www.jamesandersonjr.com, and not sub-folders/sub-directories too?

Note: In the case of a complete code rewrite, I need to be able to retain the url arguments/variables (esp. 'GET') too (esp. in the last rule, in the code above). For example:

`http://www.jamesandersonjr.com/bugreport.php?page_domain=http://www.example.com`

automatically becomes:

`http://www.jamesandersonjr.com/bug_report.php?page_domain=http://www.example.com`

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try wrapping your rules with this:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.jamesandersonjr.com'">
    ...
</If>
```

**Update**

To include subdomains and the root domain without any subdomain (just jamesandersonjr.com):

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /(?:^|\.)jamesandersonjr\.com$/">
    ...
</If>
```

To include subdomains but not the root domain:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /\.jamesandersonjr\.com$/">
    ...
</If>
```

That is for subdomains to any level. It would need to be updated if you only wanted a single level of subdomains to be allowed.

And for reference, the [documentation is here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).

Comment: Hey SuperDuperApps, please escape those periods, so I can approve your answer. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't need escaped periods. It's a string comparison, not a regex. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Now, how would I *include* sub-domains of `jamesandersonjr.com`, while still *excluding* the other websites in the sub-directories of the root?

Comment: Now you need a regex :) I updated the answer with a way to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to use it to redirect all `Http://` request to `https://` using `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` but the `if` condition you gave me is throwing an error 500. :-(

Comment: I don't think you can use mod_rewrite in conditional blocks. Just check the host in your mod_rewrite: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:^|\.)jamesandersonjr\.com$` and don't bother with the `<If>` block

Comment: The syntax was wrong on the regexes, I updated it, perhaps you won't get the error now. If you do, please check the error log for what the actual error is, just telling me it's a 500 is not much help.